# Eclipse GIT pull and push operation on single file

Tags: eclipse, egit

I want to perform Pull and push on single file.

I follow below procedure for pull:

1. right click on file **Team**
2. Click on **repository**
3. Then go with **pull**

But I observed it pull all the file from project instead of single file.

Please help with valid procedure to  perform single file push or pull operation using **E-git**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.push operation on file
we have push option in eclipse on file level But once you hit Push on any level(project level or file level) it will push all the git local commits to remote repository.

2.Pull operation on file

we have pull option in eclipse on file level But once you hit pull on any level(project level or file level) it will pull entire project from remote repository.

if you want particular file updated with remote repository please perform below action.

1.Right click on file–→Replace With-→branch tag or reference→ Remote tracking→ select branch from which you want to take latest file.